# instantiate application object and initialize a list

Tags: c#

I want to instantiate application object and initialize a list with it.
I have this code in VB.net but I cant convert it to C#.
this is VB code:

```
If Not IsNothing(Application("MessageList")) Then
   MessageList = Application("MessageList")
End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to compare the Application collection object with `null`. Also type cast the object returned by `Application` collection to `MessageList` if `MessageList` is a type.

<del>if(Application["MessageList"] != null)
     MessageList = (List) Application["MessageList"];</del>

**Edit** based on comments

The `MessageList` of `List` of `Message` and declared

```
List<Message> MessageList = new List<Message>();
```

Your condition would be.

```
 if(Application["MessageList"] != null)
        MessageList = (List<Message>) Application["MessageList"];
```

Comment: It did not work. It says Message list is a field but use like a type

Comment: What is type of MessageList ?

Comment: List<Message> MessageList = new List<Message>();